# Java Maven plugin Parameter validation

Tags: java, maven, validation, plugins, maven-plugin

I'm creating a maven plugin which accepts parameters, the parameter which is being accepted is an object with fields, and I want to enforce some constraints on those fields, what would be options to do it ? I was thinking to add `hibernate-validator` but maybe there are more lightweight options to achieve this. In this example I want to enforce max length on name field and validate if it is correct email address via regex.

Here's my Parameter class:

```
 public class Person {

  private String name;
  private String email;

  public Person() {
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

}
```

And Mojo class using this Parameter:

```
@Mojo(name = "test")
public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(required = true, readonly = true)
  private Person person;

  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {...}

}
```

Comment: Why not just check in `execute()` and throw an exception if the check does not succeed?

Comment: @JFMeier You mean invoke hibernate validator in execute method ? Or manually check each field ?

Comment: I mean just manually check for each field if it fulfils the regex.